# Could not find HttpResponse in httpclient 4.3.3

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I try to implement a simple http program which send the request and get response from the given URL.For that i use httpclient 4.3.3 jar add as an external library to my project.But the problem is,I could not find the HttpResponse in the jar file.And also i want to handle NTLM authentication in this application.please help me.

Sample code:

```
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com/?q=java");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I strongly suggest using maven (or gradle) to manage your dependencies. Next to the `httpclient` jar you also need the [`httpcore`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.httpcomponents%7Chttpcore%7C4.3.2%7Cjar) jar.

Comment: @M.Deinum. Ya tnx for ur quick reply Deinum. Initially I tried with maven dependencies,but the same error occur in that also so, i try as separate project.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I don't known what's the problem.Could you please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Add the dependency as I mentioned in the initial response. Without the httpcore.jar it isn't going to work.